# Guzzlehttp - Correct way to get same callback called immediately when each request done

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

While using Guzzle for async requests, I want got same callback immediately  when each request done.

Following code is works, but I think it's may not make sense.

Does Guzzle provide any method like `Promise\settle($promises)->then($callback)->wait()` but for each requests get done?

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org/']);

// I want got callback immediately when each request done.
$callback = function($response) {
    echo $response->getBody();
};

$promises = [
    $client->getAsync('/delay/8')->then($callback),
    $client->getAsync('/delay/4')->then($callback),
    $client->getAsync('/delay/2')->then($callback),
    $client->getAsync('/delay/1')->then($callback),
];
Promise\settle($promises)->wait();
```